# where is the "Build Drop Location" defined in Release manager 2013

Tags: ms-release-management

I build a website using Visual Studio 2013 to a location on the build server which I will call server017. The website, which I will call MyWeb is built and the output is stored in the build location c:\Builds...._PublishedWebsites

I have tried running release manager manually, forcing it to navigate to _PublishedWebsites, however I have no control over the "Build drop location" that you define in the components section of Release Manager->Config Apps

Perhaps the "Build drop location" is passed to release manager from the build? If I can control the "path to package" and specifically the "Build drop location" I believe my problems may be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You tie a build definition to a release template. The components you use within a release template will pull the build drop location from the build you're releasing.

Comment: I cant get it to output to a UNC location (despite all relevant accounts having full access).  I've tried pointing release manager 2013 to the build working directory (namely _publishwebsites) but again it throws a fit and cannot interpret the path combinations (build drop location (null in my case) and path

Answer (score 0):

I changed the output to use a UNC path and checked the access once more. The build and release tools\process are operated using the network service account. I added this to the UNC share. 
In Release Manager, be careful which path you add. Your drop area might be defined to build as \server123\Release. When the build deploys to this, it will add the full output structure i.e. buildname\buildnumber\_publishwebsites.. When adding a path to release manager, just add the value "_publishwebsites". Everything before this point is managed by the "build drop location" reference as @Daniel says